# Catch Both Positive and Negative Numbers Using Grep

Tags: regex, linux, unix, ubuntu, grep

I have code where I use Grep to search for numbers within some html code.

Below is what I have so far:

```
grep -ioP '&deg;C">[0-9]*</a></p>' ${site}_ec_wk1
```

Instead of having two entries for both positive and negative numbers, like:

```
grep -ioP '&deg;C">[0-9]*</a></p>' ${site}_ec_wk1
grep -ioP '&deg;C">-[0-9]*</a></p>' ${site}_ec_wk1
```

How can I catch both negative and positive numbers using just one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be thinking along the lines of:

```
grep -ioP '&deg;C">[-+]?[0-9]+</a></p>' ${site}_ec_wk1
                   ^^^^^     ^
                    add    change
```

This will allow for an optional sign (either positive *or* negative) and also requires at least one digit in your number: `+` means one or more, `*` means zero or more.

Answer (score 0):

Use a quantifier for the `-` sign:

```
grep -ioP '&deg;C">-?\d*</a></p>' ${site}_ec_wk1
```

Comment: Just tested this and it only displays the positive number.